# DAX Query to Calculate % Difference

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Gender  Salary  PayGrade
M       40000    3
F       35000    3
M       50000    5
M       65000    7
```

I'm creating a PowerBI visual that should display a horizontal bar for each pay grade, showing the $ difference by gender. I.E. In PayGrade 3, males are paid $5000 more than females in this example.

How can I structure a DAX query to model this? Should be something like

```
=IF(SUM(MaleSalaries) > SUM(FemaleSalaries),
    SUM(MaleSalaries) - SUM(FemaleSalaries) / COUNT(FemaleSalaries)).
```

I'm assuming the partitioning by grade will happen in the visualization.

Edit: Here's my DAX queries for the gap, and the gender column:

```
WageGap = IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender])) > 1,
             IF(CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "M") > 
             CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "F"),CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "M") -
             CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "F"),CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "F") -
             CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]), 'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender] = "M"))
             ,0)


ColumnGender = IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender]))>1,IF(CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]),'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender]="M")>CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Annualized Salary]),'Ex 6A-Salary Analysis'[Gender]="F"),"M","F"),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the difference in average salaries per `PayGrade`, I think you would want something like the following:

```
WageGap = IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(Pay[Gender]) > 1,
             CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Pay[Salary]), Pay[Gender] = "M") - 
             CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Pay[Salary]), Pay[Gender] = "F")
             ,0)
```

Where `Pay` is your data table and you have `PayGrade` on your chart axis.

This measure first tests if there are more than one gender in a certain pay grade and then takes the difference of the average salaries.

---

**Edit:**

It looks like you're trying to make this into a tornado chart. To get that to work, you'll need two separate measures that can be defined using the measure I wrote above.

```
Men = IF([WageGap] > 0, [WageGap], BLANK())
Women = IF([WageGap] < 0, -[WageGap], BLANK())
```

Try putting those two measures into your values for the visual.

Comment: This is close, but I need an IF in there to see which gender is greater for each pay grade. I.E. it will only show ONE bar for each pay grade, either the male one or the female one.

Comment: I was able to integrate the IF statement. My DAX query and chart: https://ibb.co/bBE60m
https://ibb.co/eVJYfm ... I would add that ideally, if there's only a male or female (but not both) in a given pay grade, then no value should display.

Comment: Perhaps this could be achieved with the measure in the image above, coupled with an extra column that denoted "M" or "F" based on which was greater for that pay grade?

Comment: I suspect that instead of `COUNT(Pay[Gender]) > 1` you should really use `COUNTROWS(VALUES(Pay[Gender])) > 1` or `DISTINCTCOUNT(Pay[Gender]) > 1` because these both count the number of distinct values. The first expression will return true if there are two rows with the same gender.

Comment: I have incorporated DISTINCTCOUNT and now nothing displays.

Comment: @gattoun Can you post that formula as text instead of an image? Or at least run it through http://www.daxformatter.com/

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've added them above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Additionally, I've uploaded the pbix file here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgZ70kTLVb-X0RIMjlIM3VfbU0/view?usp=sharing